# Find the same key in other localization json-file

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, intellij-plugin

I want to find the same key in an other jsons localization file. 
My json’s looks like this.

```
{
  "general": {
    "main": {
      "title": "This is a title",
      "header": "This is a header",
      "sub": {
        "sub_thing_1": "Something",
        "sub_thing_2": "Something2"
      }
    }
  },
  "other_things": {
    "title": "Other title"
    "sub": {
       "sub_thing_1": "Something",
       "sub_thing_2": "Something2"
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see the same key can be in more places

My thinking is, to generate a collection that contains, the depth values like this

eg: this "sub_thing_2" can be found at -> ["general", "main", "sub"]

and with this information i can find the exact key in other files.

And with this code I geathering the depth information for each key, it’s just a scratch, thinkering code fragement, I'm new to Kotlin by the way

```
psi?.accept(object : JsonRecursiveElementVisitor() {
    override fun visitObject(o: JsonObject) {
        val childrens = o.children
        for (child in childrens) {
            val childProp = child as JsonProperty
            if (child.lastChild is JsonObject) {
                depth.add(childProp.name)
                visitObject(child.lastChild as JsonObject)
            } else {
                println(depth.toString() + childProp.name + ": " + childProp.lastChild.text)
            }
        }

        if (depth.isNotEmpty()) {
            val lastItem = depth.last();
            depth.remove(lastItem)
        }
    }
})
```

My question is there is other easier way to do this maybe without the PSI or I'm in the right direction?